# Unable to get value from Descendants() or Element() using XML

Tags: c#, xml

I can't seem to get a value from child nodes of an xml file.  I feel like I have tried everything.  All I want is to get the value of `latitude` and `longitude` of the `location` child node in the xml file. What am I doing wrong?  Maybe I should try JSON instead of XML.

```
private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    try
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
        XElement root = xdoc.Root;
        XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;

        List<XElement> results = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "GeocodeResponse").Descendants(ns + "result").ToList();
        List<XElement> locationElement = results.Descendants(ns + "geometry").Descendants(ns + "location").ToList();
        List<XElement> lat = locationElement.Descendants(ns + "lat").ToList();
        List<XElement> lng = locationElement.Descendants(ns + "lng").ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message)
    }
}
```

xml

```
<GeocodeResponse>
    <status>OK</status>
    <result>
        <type>street_address</type>
        <formatted_address>134 Gearger Circle, Lexington, KY, USA</formatted_address>
    <geometry>
        <location>
            <lat>36.31228546</lat>
            <lng>-91.4444399</lng>
        </location>
        <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
    </geometry>
    <place_id>ChIJtwDV05mW-IgRyJKZ7fjmYVc</place_id>
    </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Also here is a debug value that shows a count of zero. not sure what that means. I just need the value of `lat` and `lng`.

Comment: You image contains json data. Are you sure your response stream is returning Xml

Comment: Sorry about that.  I included the wrong pic.  I just fixed it though.

Comment: In the picture there's a `<string>` tag surrounding the `<?xml>`. Did you get rid of that? How?  What is the xDoc.Root.Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are looking for the list of all the `lat` and `lng` in the XML Document.

```
XDocument xdc = XDocument.Load(stream);
var AllLats = xdc.Descendants("lat");
var AllLong = xdc.Descendants("lng");
```

You wont need to drill down to the hierarchy to get the XML Nodes value with `Descendants`

Another part is `ns` that is your `namespace` has to be included for the XML which looks like

```
<SOmeNS:address_component>
```

not for the elements which does have name without `:`

attaching the screenshot to see if you want this output.

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Actually I just need the `lat` and `lng` of `location`.  Sorry that wasn't clear.  I changed the contents of my question.

Comment: So you mean to say you want list of location which contains long and lat. Is it ??

Comment: I guess so.  I ultimately want a to declare a variable that contains the value of just `lat` in location.  And another variable `lng` that contains the longitude in location.  But I don't know how to do that or why my code isn't working.

Comment: @jedinerd did you tried the code I have posted. Bcoz I believe it give the list of lng and lat of your XML.

Comment: I see in your pic that you have everything working.  But I don't have any content in my Results View when debugging...  I guess there is something wrong with `stream`.  It isn't throwing errors.  So idk what is going on.

Comment: I will add a pic of what I get.  My results don't have anything.

Comment: Make sure you have data in the stream. Debug to see if the data is coming in the stream and xdoc. Have a look on [XDocument.Load Stream Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Get the element you are interested in by name. Then get the first and last child node since the first child is lat and the last child is long.

```
var sw = doc.Descendants("location");
var lat = sw.Descendants().First();
var lng = sw.Descendants().Last();
```

Comment: Actually I just need the `lat` and `lng` of `location`.  Sorry that wasn't clear.  I changed the contents of my question.

Comment: @jedinerd see edit please. Same idea but just use "location". See last three lines of code.

Comment: I just tried that and it says that `XDocument` doesn't have a definition for `GetElementsByTagName`.  Not sure why.

Comment: @jedinerd sorry just realized you are using XDocument. Edit should work.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works correctly, make sure your xml loaded in the line using debugger.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
```

And check namespace, when executing your code i got empty string in ns or try removing the ns from your code.

```
XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
```

To get the lat and long use below code.

```
List<XElement> lat = locationElement.Descendants(ns + "lat").ToList();
                List<XElement> lng = locationElement.Descendants(ns + "lng").ToList();

var latitudeval = lat[0].value;
var longitudeval = lng[0].value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
  XNamespace ns = xdoc.GetDefaultNamespace();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to fix my issue was to send a request for `JSON` instead of `XML`.  Then using `Regex` I was able to remove the `<string>` portion of the response.  This worked perfectly and JSON is easier to work with in my opinion anyways.

```
private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    JObject jdoc = null;

    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();

    try
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        Regex rgx = new Regex("<.*\\>");
        string newResult = rgx.Replace(text, "");

        JObject json = JObject.Parse(newResult);
        jdoc = json;
        JArray results = (JArray)json["results"];

        if (results.Count == 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            foreach(JObject obj in results)
            {
               string formattedAddress = (string)obj["formatted_address"];
               double lat = (double)obj["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
               double lng = (double)obj["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
            }
        }                      
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```